# Largest and smallest eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

How to show that the largest and smallest eigenvalues of a **hermitian** matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $ can be found as:
$\displaystyle \lambda_{max} = \underset{x\neq0}{\max{\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}}}$ and $\displaystyle \lambda_{min} = \underset{x\neq0}{\min{\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}}}$

Comment: [Min-max theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem). The proof is straightforward once you have taken an orthonormal basis. But note this gives a neat characterization of every $\lambda_k$, not only the first one and the last one. When they are ordered, I mean.

Comment: I meant an orthonormal diagonalization basis for $A$.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

- Convince yourself that it is ok to remove the norm term $x^Hx$ from denominator and you have to consider $x^Hx=1$ instead of $x\neq 0$.
- There exists a decomposition $A=U^HDU$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eignevalues and $U$ is the orthonormal matrix with eigenvectors.
- Define $y=Ux$, then $x^HAx=y^HDy=\sum_{i=1}^{N}|y_i|^2\lambda_i$
- Let $\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\lambda_3<\dots<\lambda_N$ be $N$ real numbers. Let $\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_N$ be $N$ non-negative numbers such that $\sum_{i}^{N}\theta_i=1$, then $\max_{\theta_i}\sum_{i}^{N}\theta_i\lambda_i=\lambda_N$ and $\min_{\theta_i}\sum_{i}^{N}\theta_i\lambda_i=\lambda_1$

Comment: May be you can also help at this related question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187850/an-analytic-characterization-of-eigenvalues-of-a-hermitian-matrix